# When does Django's custom model field method to_python get anything other than an instance?

Tags: django, django-models

From the [documentation for `to_python`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python):

> As a general rule, [`to_python`] should deal gracefully with any of the following arguments:
>
> - An instance of the correct type (e.g., `Hand` in our ongoing example).
> - A string (e.g., from a deserializer).
> - Whatever the database returns for the column type you're using.

I'm looking at my test coverage (using coverage.py), and the bit of code at the top of my `to_python`:

```
def to_python(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, Hand):
        return value

    # More code for handling strings below (I never get here)
```

is the only bit of my `to_python` method that gets called. What else should I be testing? I've tested saving and retrieving objects from the database, and I've tested serialization like this:

```
   cereal = serializers.serialize('json',
                                   Hand.objects.all())
   objects = list(serializers.deserialize("json", cereal))
```

Comment: So `to_python` contains more code that you wrote right? Where is it used in your application? Create test cases for those situations if you can.

Comment: @SimeonVisser - it's not used in my application as far as I know. I just wonder if I can safely remove it, or if it might be used in some way that I don't know about yet by Django internals. The example `to_python` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python) includes loads of code that I don't know how to get to (other than just calling `to_python` directly).

Comment: I would add logging to see if the code is actually used in daily use or perhaps by Django when running tests. If it's not the case then there's no need to forcefully create test cases. If an error does occur, you can always add a test case later to prevent it from happening again.

Answer (score 1):

I've found one place where `to_python` ends up with something other than an instance - in the case where the value is not provided (for example, if your field is set up to allow null). In that case, because I'd implemented `get_prep_value` badly, `to_python` got passed a string containing `None`.